# How to change date language?

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

```
<table class="projects">
    <tr><td class="title" colspan="2">Vergangene Projekte</td></tr>

<?php   $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE project = 1 && project_date <= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)ORDER BY date DESC";
        if(!$query){
        die("Konnte nicht mit Data Base verbinden");}
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); // using german language works
        $premier = new DateTime($row['project_date']);
        echo "<tr><td>" .strftime("%B", $premier->getTimestamp()). "</td><td class=\"project_title\">
        <a class=\"title\" href=\"projekt_info.php?projekt=" .urlencode($row["id"]) ."\">" 
        .$row['title']. "</a></td></tr>";} 
?>
</table>
```

Ok I modified the code to show all of it and also inserted the suggestions and now it works just fine!! Perfect

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Can you try adding `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');`

Comment: Plus, is that your full code? If so, there are quite a few things missing. Table tags, data fetching for instance.

Comment: and make sure that `fr_FR` locale is indeed installed in machine. `locale -a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off make sure that indeed `fr_FR` is installed on the machine for your script to use.

Try to use `locale -a` on your terminal to check.

Second, since `DateTime` only works on english, use `strftime()` on that, and you're using it without the timestamp.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$premier = new DateTime($row['project_date']);
echo "<tr><td>" .strftime("%B", $premier->getTimestamp()). "</td><tr>";
                                   // ^^ feed the timestamp
```

Sidenote: as Fred said in the comments, this is just a fragment because your markup is a bit off (missing tags, etc, and most likely this is inside a loop).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I prefer using IntlDateFormatter which is system-locale independant and output is guaranteed to be in UTF-8:

```
$datefmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'LLLL');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    # ...
    echo "<tr><td>" . $datefmt->format($premier). "</td>"/*...*/;
    # ...
```

(see ICU's documentation for [a custom format](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details) - the last argument of IntlDateFormatter constructor)